# Eclipse m2e sometimes not showing all available dependency versions when using auto-completion in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

If I import maven projects into Eclipse, and then try to look up available maven central versions of some dependency defined in the project's pom.xml file by using auto-completion on an empty dependency version tag, it often only shows one (the previous) version although there is no problem with the maven central index and I can browse it using the repository view without problems. Other dependencies in the same pom.xml may or may not show this behavior. Why is that? Is there any fix to this issue?

**Update**

I filed a bug report. Closer inspection showed that the maven central index is being ignored for version lookups if there is *any* version of the same artifact in your local maven repository. Then only versions (or their pom.xml files) stored in your local maven repository will be shown. This is inconsistent and makes no sense.

Comment: Eclipse only show the dependency versions from local repository.

Comment: no, like I said, for some dependencies it shows all possible versions. And even if that'd be the case, it does not even show all locally existing versions.

Comment: If the remote repository is not locally indexed, you get nothing.